# MapBox Studio Satellite Data seems to be off by 2 metres

Tags: geojson, mapbox, mapbox-studio

Any `MapBox` developers noticed that their satellite imagery is way off position? It is also very bad quality compared to `Google`. I first realised that something was off when I loaded my stylised map into my app and then added markers to it that I had collected from `Google Maps` using their satellite view as a preview. Literally dropped pins and saved them so I could add them to a CMS and load them back into my app. I used `Google` for this because their satellite data was so much better than `MapBox` and I was able to see where things were (it is zoomed right in).

To illustrate how much it is off I outlined the boundary of a building in the `Google My Maps` web app and exported it as `geoJSON`. I then imported the feature into `MapBox Studio`.

[image]

Here is the result of the import compared to what I had. Look at the selected polygon and you'll see it is the main building. Notice how much it is off?

[image]

I would love to know how to use another satellite provider in `MapBox Studio Dataset` so I can compare these. I wonder if they are all slightly off?

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

I would like to use another Satellite image supplier in `Mapbox Studio` if possible. In the `dataset` editor there is an option to use a `reference raster tileset`. Would this be a link to another service?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Are you able to see the images in the post? I am seeing broken links for some reason.

Comment: Have edited the post. I am looking for specific help.